# Ubuntu 23.10 does not start connected to switches

Tags: boot, 23.10

I have two desktop machines, one with Windows and the other with Ubuntu, that share Internet and speakers through two switches. Audio selector: bidirectional switch for 3.5 mm audio switch. Desktop Switch tp-link 5-Port 10/100Mbps (TL-SF1005D). Since I updated to Ubuntu 23.10, the second PC does not turn on after using the first one (or with it running). The only way to turn it on is to cut off and then restore the power source.

Comment: Audio selector: bidirectional switch for 3.5 mm audio switch. Desktop Switch tp-link 5-Port 10/100Mbps (TL-SF1005D).